# Magento2.2.3 - Admin store configuration is save but not display in admin panel

Tags: magento2.2.3, system-config, core-config-data

I want to change *store configuration* in Magento2.2.3.

But when I try to save the configuration from admin it saved in the database (`core_config_data` table).

But not getting changed in admin store configuration, still shows old values not updated.

Does have any idea about this?

Answer (score 9):

I get the solution to this problem. If anyone faces this problem,

Require to remove `var/page_cache` and `var/session` folder. After saving the configuration, you can able to see changes in the admin panel.

And it's working properly.

Comment: hi, I don't have var/session folder in my case

Comment: running `$ rm -rf var/cache` and `$ rm -rf var/page_cache` fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 5):

First you need to check if value is saved in a database. If it is saved but is not showing in admin all you need to do is go to System>Cache Management and click on `Flush Cache Storage` link next to `Flush Magento Cache` orange button. Click OK to confirm and all will be fine after that. You can clear cache, too.

Answer (score 1):

Please run once below command :

```
php bin/magento set:up
```

and clear cache from backend and your browser

Comment: Can you give me more explaination about this?

Comment: sometimes data coming from cache. have you tried above command ?

Comment: No, setup:upgrade not required.  I removed `var/session` folder and its working propely.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario, big chance that your cron job is stuck and you are facing issue. See your cron job using ssh and if there is any cron job is stuck then kill the pid of that purticular process and your issue will be resolved.

Log in to your account using SSH.

Run the following command to locate hanging cron jobs:

@sip4-000 ~]$ ps ufx | grep cron

The output should resemble output shown below:

root 12080 0.0 0.0 117328 460 ? Ss Mar25 5:23 crond
username 26529 0.0 0.0 103244 848 pts/0 S+ 22:33 0:00 _ grep cron
username 6876 5.0 0.3 646760 88476 ? S 15:42 20:50 /usr/bin/php /chroot/home/username/domainname.com/html/cron.php -mdefault

The first line shows the cron service running on the server.
The second line shows the command that you just ran. It matches itself when looking for the word "cron" in the running services.

Most importantly, the third line shows your Magento cron job. The cron job usually runs quickly, so if it shows up here, it is likely hanging.

You can confirm a hanging cron job by checking the second column from the right. The 15:42 20:50 shows the duration of the cron job; if this duration takes longer than an hour, then it is hanging.

To stop the cron from running, kill the command by referencing the PID. Returning to the command output, the second column from the left is the PID 6876.

Run the following command to terminate the command:

[username@sip4-000 ~]$ kill -9 6876

For More detail see the following link to kill the process.
https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-find-and-remove-hanging-magento-cron-jobs-with-ssh.html

-Zahid

Comment: Not worked for me. I tried all the solutions but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Flush / clear all your cache types, and flush storage and magento cache worked for me.