# Magento 2.3 admin configurations saving in database but not reflecting on admin UI

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Recently we updated magento version from 2.2 to 2.3.x , All the catalog , orders , customers working fine but when we save data from **Store-->Configuration** , Data is saving finely in database but the values are not reflecting on Admin Panel UI.

For example , I want to enable **"Single Store Mode"** to **"Yes"** , In database it is saving as 1 but in admin panel , The setting showing as **"No"** as selected. I have only one store and one website in magento stores.

I tried below methods.

1. Cache Flush
2. Removed var/cache and var/sessions
3. Did indexer

But none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this in some Magento 2.3.x projects. I believe it only happens in some concrete versions

It is a weird issue, as it only happens sporadically. You can try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/223981/3566

If that doesn't solve the problem, you could try moving both cache & sessions to Redis. After that we've never experienced it again. More info https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html

Comment: I tried your answer but no use of it. Any other debug technique?

Comment: Is it related to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23133 this?

Comment: You could try upgrading to latest 2.3.x version

Comment: That is also not working... Any other debug techniques?